Android studio API is able to display all 21 records on WEB but failed to load them on APP(Android)
API failed to run on APP (Android)
API is able to load all 21 records on WEB
my code:
void LoadData() async {
  Loading = true;
  var map = convert.jsonEncode({
    "account_id": settings.AccountID.toString(),
    "records": settings.Records.toString(),
    "recommend": '1',
  });
  final response = await api_HomePage(map);
  var raw = convert.jsonDecode(response.body)[0];
  print("api_homepage");
  debugPrint(response.body);
  totalRecords = raw["count"];
  if (totalRecords > 0) {
    dataList = parseJson(raw["datalist"]);
  } else {
    dataList = [];
  }
  setState(() {
    Loading = false;
  });
}

if print(raw), it shows the following error
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double?'
print(raw) and shows error. failed to load 21 records on APP(Android)
change int type to double or num
First, I have tried to change 'int' type to 'double', the API still fails to load all 21 records on APP(Android) but loads full 21 records without issue on WEB.
Second, I have changed 'int' & 'double' type to 'num', the API still fails to load all 21 records on APP(Android) but loads full 21 records without issue on WEB.
